# setOnItemClickListener event not working

Tags: android, events, listview, simpleadapter

I have `listView` and `SimpleAdapter`, which setup my `listView`. But `setOnItemClickListener` event is not raised.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mContext = this;
  setContentView(R.layout.add_item_from_subcateg);
  subcategName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("subcategName");
  mySQLWorker = new MySQLWorker(this);
  mySQLWorker.open();
  list_view_products = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  finishLoading(null);
}

public void finishLoading(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> result)
{

  HashMap<String, Object> hashmap;
  List<ProductInfo> products = mySQLWorker.GetProductsByCategory(subcategName);


  for (ProductInfo product : products) 
  {
     hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     hashmap.put("ItemID", product.getID());
     hashmap.put("image_product", product.getImagePath());
     hashmap.put("product_name", product.getName());
     hashmap.put("lbl_protein_count", product.getProtein());
     hashmap.put("lbl_fat_count", product.getFat());
     hashmap.put("lbl_carbohydrates_count", product.getCarbohydrates());
     list_products.add(hashmap);
  }


  adapterProductsList = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list_products,
  R.layout.product_template, new String[] { "image_product",
  "product_name", "lbl_protein_count",
  "lbl_fat_count", "lbl_carbohydrates_count" }, new int[] {  

  R.id.image_product,R.id.product_name, R.id.lbl_protein_count,
  R.id.lbl_fat_count,R.id.lbl_carbohydrates_count });
        list_view_products.setAdapter(adapterProductsList);
        adapterProductsList.notifyDataSetChanged();         
        progress_dialog.dismiss();

        list_view_products.setOnItemClickListener(new
  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long
  arg3)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "312", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank's for advance !

UPD:

ListView layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/lv_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/lv_item_bg"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_product"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/title_default_value"
        android:textColor="@color/gold_color" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lbl_protein"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="@string/protein_label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lbl_protein_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_protein"
            android:text="@string/gramm_default"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lbl_fat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_protein"
            android:text="@string/fat_label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lbl_fat_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_fat"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_protein_count"               
            android:text="@string/gramm_default"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lbl_carbohydrates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_fat"
            android:text="@string/carbohydrates_label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lbl_carbohydrates_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_carbohydrates"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_fat_count"
            android:text="@string/gramm_default"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btn_more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/spinner_ab_holo_light"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: paste you Listview's layout file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your ImageButton is stealing away the onItemClickLister event. Add this attribute  to your layout

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

And also remove android:clickable="true" thing.
So it should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lv_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_product"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp" />
......
```

Thanks